# Typing arguments with number | enum, for documentation purposes

Tags: typescript

Given an enum:

```
const enum BasicColor {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}
```

and a method which can take either values from the said `enum` or any arbitrary number:

```
function foo(someColor: number | BasicColor) {
    // do something here
}
```

should I type this way to indicate to callers that both kinds of values are appropriate here?

Or, since typing with either `number` or `BasicColor` allows passing in all the same values (because `enum`-typed arguments take any number), and either call will compile in any case:

```
function bar(color: number) {
}
bar(BasicColor.Red);

function baz(color: BasicColor) {
}
baz(42);
```

the type system should not be leveraged to provide documentation?

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20enum%20BasicColor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Red%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Green%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Blue%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(color%3A%20number%20%7C%20BasicColor)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20bar(color%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Abar(BasicColor.Red)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20baz(color%3A%20BasicColor)%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Abaz(42)%3B%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1):

> the type system should not be leveraged to provide documentation?

It's not strictly about the documentation, I think that type annotations in general facilitate  understanding the code. From this point of view, making it `number | BasicColor` is better because making things explicit is usually better.

Also, TypeScript developers continue adding various `--strict` flags to the compiler, so it's possible that in the future passing any number as `enum`-typed argument will become an error in strict mode.

Comment: At least in VS Code, `number | BasicColor` collapses to `number` in the code hint for the `foo` parameter.  So while it is nice for documentation if someone looks up the definition, the tooling doesn't make it easy.  I wonder if there's some reasonable way around it...

Comment: @jcalz It seems as though VS Code is taking this information from the Typescript language service; the Typescript Playground also shows the type of the argument as collapsed to `number`.